# How to set Max Height for RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to set Max Height of RecyclerView?
I have a RecyclerView as follows:

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_goods">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

When the items of recyclerview  are too many, the recyclerview will be too high.

Can I set the max height of the recyclerview ?

when the recyclerview grow to the max height,The recyclerview will not grow up and the items of recyclerview can be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of RecyclerView and override onMeasure method.

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Utils.dpsToPixels(the_height_you_want), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConstraintLayout` to wrap `RecyclerView` and others, set their constraint and set `minHeight` for view belows `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**xml code**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="21sp"/>

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp">   //increases your recycleview height  
       </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

      </LinearLayout>


      </FrameLayout>
```

**java code**

if your item on ***wrap content***

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=recycler_view.getLayoutParams();
params.height= RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
recycler_view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and

```
<dimen name="view_height">250dp</dimen>

float height= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.view_height); //get height

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params_new=recycler_view.getLayoutParams();
params_new.height=height;
recycler_view.setLayoutParams(params_new);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simplest solution**: You can put `RecyclerView` with `android:layout_height"match_parent"` in a parent layout (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout,...) with specific height.

Comment: but when the item is 0, there is an empty area of the layout. I do not want to be that.

Comment: If item size = 0, you can setVisibility(GONE) for it.

Comment: I what the max height is 150dp  if the size =1 or 2 or 3 , the empty area is still there.